# Changing Printer Preferences via GPO

Tags: printing, group-policy

The short question is ..... is there a way to set Printer Preferences via a GPO?

Now the long question.... I mean so the users can't change Printing Preferences on their workstations. This question is prevalent on the internet but there is no answer. People mis-interpret the question. The answer usually given is (on the server) right click=>Properties=>Advanced=>Printing defaults but...

That is not the answer. That is how you control Printing Defaults but has nothing to do with controlling Printing Preferences. Anyone want to take a shot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to disable printer preferences through GPO or through any other way actually. The only thing you can do is set some defaults but the users can then change them anyways.

Here is a thread where a similar question was asked and a Microsoft employee responded that there is no way to disable this: 
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/6440d223-e875-4663-9c4a-90235f2b1b36/disable-printer-properties?forum=winserverGP